# How to get Rscript to run through docker?

Tags: r, macos, docker, terminal, dockerfile

I am trying to get my Rscript to run through a list of data sets on docker. I have gotten the dockerfile set up correctly and it runs fine, the docker image builds fine, but everytime it tries to run through the Rscript, I get this error:

```
/app/model-1.r: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `mosaic'
/app/model-1.r: line 24: `library(mosaic)'
```

My image is based on r-ver in the dockerfile, which also installs all the necessary packages, and I have a command to run the script:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.0

RUN R -e "install.packages('mosaic', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
COPY /model-1.r .
CMD R -e "source('/model-1.r')"
```

and I've tried adding this command to the Rscript document itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(mosaic)
```

but nothing has worked. Is there something glaring that I am missing here?

This is the 'run' command that I am using in the terminal:

```
docker run \
     -v $(pwd)/synthetic_data:/data:ro \
     -v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw \
     -v $(pwd)/scratch:/scratch:rw \
     awesome-model:v1 bash /app/model-1.r
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What's in `model-1.r` exactly? Is it only the `library(mosaic)` line? The error says "line 24" so I'm trying to figure out what the extra lines might be.

Comment: Sorry about that--the other lines are notes describing the model, non-executable. Ex: 
### Load synthetic data
### YZ re-download the data on 6/19/2020.
### Data source: synthetic_data.tar.gz updated on 5/22/2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this command:

```sh
docker run \
     -v $(pwd)/synthetic_data:/data:ro \
     -v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw \
     -v $(pwd)/scratch:/scratch:rw \
     awesome-model:v1 bash /app/model-1.r
```

The last arguments, `bash /app/model-1.r`, tell Docker to ignore the `CMD` specified by the Dockerfile and interpret `/app/model-1.r` as a Bash script. You probably want to replace `bash` with `Rscript`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out--I needed to run a separate text file as the command so that my terminal knew that it was reading an Rscript.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

Rscript /app/model-1.R
```

Without the Rscript command, I'm pretty sure it was expecting bash or something like that. So my new command is:

```
docker run \
     -v $(pwd)/synthetic_data:/data:ro \
     -v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw \
     -v $(pwd)/scratch:/scratch:rw \
     awesome-model:v1 bash /app/command.txt
```

where command.txt is just a text file containing the above lines.